# How to retrieve all data from azure database with tyescript?

Tags: typescript, azure-storage

I created a CRUD application with typescript querying azure storage table. I can get a single record from the database , but haven't figured out how to retrieve all data. any help ? here's my code for getting a single record and an attempt to get all records :

```
async getSystem(partitionKey: string, rowKey: string): 
Promise<Array<System>> {
    return new Promise<Array<System>>((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        this.tableService.retrieveEntity<Array<System>>(
          this.tableName,
          partitionKey,
          rowKey,
          (err, entity) => {
            if (err){ reject(err) };
            resolve(this.tableRecordToJavacript(entity));
          }
        );
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }

      async getAllSystem(): Promise<Array<System>> {
    return new Promise<Array<System>>((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const query = new azure.TableQuery().top(100);
        this.tableService.queryEntities<Array<System>>(
          this.tableName,
          query,
          null,
          (err, entitites) => {
            if (err){ reject(err) };
            resolve(this.tableRecordToJavacript(entitites));
          }
        );
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }


  private tableRecordToJavacript(entity: Array<System>): Array<System> {
    let result: any = {};
    Object.keys(entity).forEach(k => {
      // we do not want to decode metadata
      if (k !== ".metadata") {
        let prop = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(entity, k);
        if (prop) {
          result[k] = prop.value["_"];
        }
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript is TypeScript : Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program.
TypeScript provides compile time type safety for your JavaScript code. This is no surprise given its name. The great thing is that the types are completely optional. Your JavaScript code .js file can be renamed to a .ts file and TypeScript will still give you back valid .js equivalent to the original JavaScript file. TypeScript is intentionally and strictly a superset of JavaScript with optional Type checking
https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-table.html

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.
If you are getting any error message or error code, please share the screen shot